# Как начать ключ массива с 0

Tags: php, массивы

```
[keyboard] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Роллы
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Соки Напитки
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Дополнительно
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Сеты 
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Десерты 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Салаты
                    )

            )
```

Есть массив, как я могу внутри каждого массива ключ начинать с 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы про вложенные массивы, то можете перенумеровать примерно так:

```
foreach($data['keyboard'] as &$d){
    $d = array_values($d);
}
```

или

```
$result['keyboard'] = array_map('array_values', $data['keyboard']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```
<?
  $a = array (0 => 'Text 0', 1 => 'Text 1');
  print_r($a);
?>
```

Или вот так:

```
<?
  $a = array ('Text 0', 'Text 1');
  print_r($a);
?>
```

Добавлено в связи с комментарием под ответом...
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php

**preserve_keys**
Если установлено в TRUE, ключи оригинального массива будут сохранены. По умолчанию установлено в FALSE, что **переиндексирует** каждую часть с числовыми ключами

Comment: Мне не надо вручную

Comment: А у вас гдето есть пример того как создан этот массив?

Comment: $test = array_chunk($tes , 2, true);

Comment: Так гляньте доку на функцию которой пользуетесь =)

Comment: чего минусите-то, по комментам к правильному ответу пришли

Comment: Видимо обида что отправил читать доку =)